# Ext.js: Vbox layout how to make the first item take all the space when the second item is hidden?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a panel with a vbox layout, inside there two panels, one in the top, and one in the bottom. Through some actions, I hide the bottom panel by invoking its hide() method. How can I now make the top panel to take all the spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function(){

    var p1 = new Ext.panel.Panel({
        flex: 1,
        title: 'Top panel'
    });

    var p2 = new Ext.panel.Panel({
        title: 'Bottom panel',
        flex: 1
    });

    new Ext.container.Viewport({
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [p1, p2]
    });

    var visible = true;
    setInterval(function(){
        if (visible) {
            p2.hide();
        } else {
            p2.show();
        }
        visible = !visible;
    }, 1000);

});
```